# PHP post particular content to facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently developing this website "http://mica.com.my/cmstest/main/event.php".
I have few different content to be ready to post to facebook if user clicked the "Share" button. But when user click the share button it share the whole page which i don't wish to do that, how can i only share on the particular post's content to facebook but not the whole website page?

I had try to implement facebook api in it, but it still alway share the whole page instead of only the particular content to faccebook.

Please guide me through this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to add meta description to the header.

```
<meta name="og:description" content="this will be the description shared on facebook">
```

you can also use other meta data like image , url and title. you can see all the otions in [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#u_0_17)